# A gap in Hardy's proof that (for positive $\delta$) $\frac {\log x} {x^\delta} \to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

After Hardy (*Introduction to Theory of Numbers*, p.10) proves that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {e^x} {x^n} = \infty, n > 0$, he goes on to state:

> It follows that $\log x$, the inverse function, tends to infinity more slowly than any positive power of $x$; $\log x \to \infty$, but $\frac {\log x} {x^\delta} \to 0$... for every positive $\delta$.

While the intuition here is obvious, how is this a proof? Is Hardy assuming for any function $f$ that $\frac {f(x)} {x^n} \to \infty$ implies $\frac {f^{-1}(x)} {x^n} \to 0$?

How is that proven, and why does Hardy take it as self-evident?

Comment: Take $n=1$ and $y=\delta \log x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and apply the above, so $e^y/y \to \infty$ getting $x^{\delta}/(\delta \log x) \to \infty$; since $\delta$ is fixed positive constant, result follows

Answer (score 0):

No, $\frac{f(x)}{x^n}\to \infty$ tells us that $\frac u{f^{-1}(u)^n}\to \infty$. Now reciprocate and take the $\delta=1/n$ power.

Comment: Ted, should that be $f^{-1}(u^n)$? If not, can you please clarify with parenthesis what the $\_^n$ is modifying.

Comment: Sorry. No, $u=f(x)$, so $x=f^{-1}(u)$ and $x^n =(f^{-1}(u))^n$.

Comment: @Conrad’s approach is the direct one, but I was trying to follow/correct your line of reasoning.